# Add a control into two containers

Tags: winforms, controls

How can I add a control into two different containers at the same time?

For example: I have `TabPage1`, `TabPage2` and a textbox control. I want the textbox be added into both `TabPage1` and `TabPage2` at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that it's not possible to have a control in two containers at the same time. A simple workaround, which works most of the time (especially in case of tab control), is to move the control from one container to the other when the other container becomes visible (for example when the user switches tab pages).